# How can i ensure that when I restart my computer or I use another computer I can access the same HashiCorp Vault that I will initially setup?

Tags: python, key, vault, hashicorp

I've setup hashicorp vault with username and password with policies but whenever I restart my computer to access the same vault with the username and password it doesnt seem to work